# XSL-FO page break depending on fullness of previous page

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I need to insert a page break in XSL-FO if previous page content ends on >60% of page height only. For example, if the text on page 'one' occupies 30% of page height, then the text of next section puts on this page on continue of previous text. Otherwise, the new page will be created.
Is it possible in FOP or not?

Comment: I don't see any way to do this. The FO processor cannot conditionally add a page break depending on the "fullness" of a page. It would require 1) somehow measuring the "fullness" and 2) feeding back this information to the processor. Such a mechanism does not exist in XSL-FO.

Comment: I do not know a way to do it but would not share @mzjn's pessimism. The issue is inside the xsl fo processor e.g. in the same way that avoids page breaks before paragraphs' last lines or alike - just in this case there would have to be a bonus for breaking if 60% fill is exceeded (though that obviously never will be an exact limit)

Comment: @mzjn is correct. XSL FO as a specification and the majority of processors were not designed to "look behind" or more appropriately "change formatting" based on what is behind me. There are a few exceptions like footnotes which change what can be on a page (which could of course move the content that references the footnote off the page) ... but those are pretty well known. What the OP wants is not inside the core of XSL FO products but can be programmed if desired, sacrificing greatly on performance.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you cannot. XSL FO and the corresponding formatters were designed for batch operations and not conducting look ahead (or look behind) operations to make decisions, especially if those decisions depend on page location. In normal batch formatting operations you have to restrict your thought process to what should be kept together and what should not be. The instant you start to think "I would like a conditional page break here if the content exceeds X% of the page" you are off track and the products "out-of-the-box" were not designed to requirements like that. Those are requirements normally for a multi-pass formatting engine that is much, much slower in nature.

You can accomplish your task but only through custom programming integrated into the process. You can investigate more in places like this link where some folks are extending the ability to interact with the formatter during the formatting process: https://www.w3.org/community/ppl/wiki/XSLTExtensions

IMHO, if you want a solution that performs then you need to make decisions on how to fit content ahead of time and not try to do things that depend on "how far did I go down the page."

Comment: The ["Decision making in XSL-FO formatting"](http://www.balisage.net/Proceedings/vol10/print/Graham01/BalisageVol10-Graham01.html) conference paper from 2013 may be of interest. Abstract: "XSL-FO has a very linear processing model that has served it well, but very often it is necessary to make decisions on what will be in the formatted output based on the sizes of the formatted output, and XSL 1.1 as defined does not let you do that. This paper looks at what's needed to be done to get that sort of decision making into XSL-FO processing today and at some possible future developments."

Comment: +! @mzjn for sure. I have read that paper. Its a matter of deciding between what is truly appropriate for lights-out formatting and whether that needs to be brought back into what is traditionally in interactive, hands-on formatters. Are they needed or not? There are certainly "cases" for it, but is there significant "market" for it. That is the true tell.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use page-sequence-master with combined simple-page-master s.

Example 1 (play with footer):

```
<fo:simple-page-master master-name="a4_rest" page-width="21cm" page-height="297mm" margin-top="{$page_margin_top}" margin-left="{$page_margin_left}" margin-right="{$page_margin_right}" margin-bottom="{$page_margin_bottom}">
    <fo:region-body/>
</fo:simple-page-master>
<fo:simple-page-master master-name="a4_footer" page-width="21cm" page-height="297mm" margin-top="{$page_margin_top}" margin-left="{$page_margin_left}" margin-right="{$page_margin_right}" margin-bottom="{$page_margin_bottom}">
    <fo:region-body margin-bottom="{$footer_distance}"/>
    <fo:region-after extent="{$footer_distance}"/>
</fo:simple-page-master>

<fo:page-sequence-master master-name="firstPage60Percent">
    <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="first" master-reference="a4_footer"/>
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="any" master-reference="a4_rest"/>
    </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
</fo:page-sequence-master>
```

You need to use the master-reference="firstPage60Percent" option in page-sequence.
So, you need to set below options in the simple-page-master named "a4_footer":

set footer_distance to 30%-page-margin-bottom

Or

set page-margin-bottom to 30%-footer_distance.

And voila.

But, what is your next section? On block-container you can use keep-together="always" or "within-page" options, so it can drop onto the next page if it is no more space on this page. Etc. I don't know your document. Need more info if you cannot resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

AH Formatter has an `axf:keep-together-within-dimension` extension for specifying a height up to which a 'keep-together' will apply. (See https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/v70e/ahf-ext.html#axf.keep-together-within-dimension)

Something like this should force a page break if there is less than 40% of the height available on the current page:

```
<fo:block keep-together.within-page="always" axf:keep-together-within-dimension="40vh">
```

See the "Limiting the height to which keep-together applies" example in the "XSL-FO Samples" page at https://www.antennahouse.com/xsl-fo-samples

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I had a dynamic table which was on two pages depending on the content above. I solved it by using the attribute:

keep-together.within-page="always"

I dont know if its possible to use it if previous page content is > 60%, but maybe it helps someone with the same problem as me.

```
<fo:block>
    <fo:block-container keep-together.within-page="always">
            <my-content>
    </fo:block-container>
</fo:block>
```

https://www.data2type.de/xml-xslt-xslfo/xsl-fo/xslfo-referenz/attribute/keep-together-within-page